# If we have multiple macros in single jinja template. How to render a particular macro in it in python

Tags: python, jinja2

Ex: name = aa.py.jinja2

```
{% macro Macro1() -%}
...
{%- endmacro %}

{% macro Macro2() -%}
...
{%-endmacro %}
```

Rendering in python

```
loader = PackageLoader(__name__, "")
env = Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template("aa.jnja2")

aa = template.render("Macro1")
```

How to render particular macro..Otherwise have to create separate template for each macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros are comparable with functions and are meant to be called. You can import `aa.jinja2` first and then call its `Macro1` function:

```
aa = env.from_string('{% import 'aa.jinja2' as aa %}{{ aa.Macro1() }}').render()
```

Comment: How to pass the parameters to that macro..i.e aa.Macro1(obj=obj)

Comment: You can define the macro with a parameter, e.g. `{% macro Macro1(obj) -%}`, and then pass a value as a keyword argument to the `render` method, e.g. `aa = env.from_string('{% import 'aa.jinja2' as aa %}{{ aa.Macro1(obj) }}').render(obj=value)`.

Comment: Thanks, will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can copy approach used by Flask in `get_template_attribute`
https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/main/src/flask/helpers.py#L315

**Example**:
`macros.j2` as Jinja template file. It can contain multiple macros, so you can have them all in one file.

```
{% macro console(content) %}
    {% if content %}
        <div class="console">{{ content|escape }}</div>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Loading the macro and using it as a function. All you have to specify is which `getattrib` you want from your macro file. Attributes correspond to the macro names, ie `console` in this snippet.

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

j2env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader("."))
macro = getattr(j2env.get_template("macros.j2").module, "console")

text = macro("I'm a <html> tag wrapped in a console div block")
print(text)
```

Result:

```html
<div class="console">I&#39;m a &lt;html&gt; tag wrapped in a console div block</div>
```